# Simple command line parsing

Tags: c, console

I'm making a project that needs a simple cross-platform command-line parser. I made this. Hope you enjoy!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define __NUM_OF_ELEMENTS(ARR) (sizeof(ARR)/sizeof(ARR[0]))
#define __HAS_ARG(FLAGS, ARG) (FLAGS & (1 << ARG))


void panic(const char *fmt, ...){
    fprintf(stderr, "error: ");

    va_list arglist;
    va_start( arglist, fmt );
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, arglist);
    va_end( arglist );

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void help(const char * progName){
    char * whoami = 0;
    (whoami = strrchr(progName, '/')) ? ++whoami : (whoami = progName);
    printf(

           "%s is intended to do blah\n"
           "Options:\n"
           " --help                Display This message\n"
           " --file [file name]    Input file to use\n",

    whoami);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1){
        help(argv[0]);
    }

    const char * args[] = {"--help", "--file", "--2cool4scool"};
    enum                  {HELP_ARG, FILE_ARG, TOO_COOL_FOR_SCHOOL_ARG};
    unsigned int flags = 0;

    //skip prog name
    for(unsigned int arg = 1, i = 0; arg < argc; ++arg){
        for(i = 0; i < (unsigned int)__NUM_OF_ELEMENTS(args); ++i){
            if(!strcmp(argv[arg], args[i])){
                flags |= 1 << i;
                goto CMD_ARGUMENT_FOUND;
            }
        }


        //argument is not found / unkown arg
        panic("Argument '%s' not found\n", argv[arg]);


        CMD_ARGUMENT_FOUND:;
    }

    if(__HAS_ARG(flags, HELP_ARG)){
        help(argv[0]);
    }
    if(__HAS_ARG(flags, TOO_COOL_FOR_SCHOOL_ARG)){
        puts("Hell YA!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a single-translation-unit program, mark your `panic` and `help` as `static`.

About this:

```
(whoami = strrchr(progName, '/')) ? ++whoami : (whoami = progName);
```

"Yikes". Generously we call this write-only code. Unroll it to

```
char *whoami = strrchr(progName, '/');
if (whoami)
    whoami++;
else
    whoami = progName;
```

In this loop, your `i` declaration should be moved down:

```
for(unsigned int arg = 1, i = 0; arg < argc; ++arg){
    for(i = 0; i < (unsigned int)__NUM_OF_ELEMENTS(args); ++i){
```

should be

```
for (unsigned int arg = 1; arg < argc; ++arg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (unsigned int)__NUM_OF_ELEMENTS(args); ++i) {
```

to narrow its scope.

Don't use `goto`. Factor out a function where the double loop termination is done using a `return`.

Comment: Thx, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: A few things to things note is the compiler will emit a warning at `for (int i = 0; i < (unsigned int) ...` as it is comparing an `int` to an `unsigned int`; I had initially declared `i` in the 1st `for` loop as it would be *technically* faster, but as you pointed out it would be better to do it the way you stated for clarity; In this example I agree `help` should be `static`, but `panic` would probably be used later in the application. With `whoami` it does make more sense to avoid the one liner;

Comment: _it would be technically faster_ - I deeply doubt this. I encourage you to profile to see whether that's the case.

Comment: Perhaps you're working under the assumption that re-declaring a variable imposes a runtime cost. It would not in this case.

Comment: I had heard something a while ago, but it doesn't really make a difference in this case besides clarity.

Answer (score 0):

These names are dangerous:

> ```
> #define __NUM_OF_ELEMENTS(ARR) (sizeof(ARR)/sizeof(ARR[0]))
> #define __HAS_ARG(FLAGS, ARG) (FLAGS & (1 << ARG))
> ```

Any identifier containing two consecutive underscores is reserved for the implementation for any purpose.  The same goes for names beginning with underscore and a capital letter.

Also, you slightly messed up the protective parentheses when expanding macro arguments:

```
#define NUM_OF_ELEMENTS(ARR) (sizeof (ARR) / sizeof (ARR)[0])
#define HAS_ARG(FLAGS, ARG) ((FLAGS) & (1 << (ARG)))
```

---

If no arguments are passed, then we hit this:

> ```
> if(argc == 1){
>     help(argv[0]);
> }
> ```

In a portable program, we should really test `argc <= 1`, since implementations are allowed to pass 0 as `argc`.  The usage message should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  And why do we continue after this?  It seems very odd to print an unasked-for usage message, but then continue and return a success status.

---

Maintaining parallel lists is tedious and error-prone.  So this code looks pretty straightforward with three possible options:

> ```
> const char * args[] = {"--help", "--file", "--2cool4scool"};
> enum                  {HELP_ARG, FILE_ARG, TOO_COOL_FOR_SCHOOL_ARG};
> ```

It becomes unmanageable once you have a few dozen options.  And it doesn't handle synonyms very well (e.g. `-f` and `--file` both being acceptable).

> ```
> flags |= 1 << i;
> ```

That ought to be `1u << i`, since `flags` is unsigned (same goes for the corresponding macro).  And this fails silently once `i` becomes greater than the width of `unsigned`, leading to a hard-to-find error.

---

> ```
>     //argument is not found / unkown arg
> ```

Typo: **unknown**

---

> ```
> if(__HAS_ARG(flags, HELP_ARG))
> if(__HAS_ARG(flags, TOO_COOL_FOR_SCHOOL_ARG))
> ```

It seems that the `--file` option is recognised but ignored.  That's almost certainly a bug.  Worse than that, the help says it should be followed by a file-name argument, but actually doing so results in an "argument not found" error.

---

It's worth reading the documentation of Python's [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module (even if you don't know Python) to see what a real argument handler can and should do.  For example, it automates printing the usage message so you don't end up forgetting to update it when you add a new option, like here:

> ```
>        "Options:\n"
>        " --help                Display This message\n"
>        " --file [file name]    Input file to use\n",
> ```

Comment: I am impressed! Although I knew a lot of compiler macros used `__` at the beginning of the names I didn't really consider that an issue. I'll use `#define lengthof(ARR) (sizeof (ARR) / sizeof (ARR)[0])` next time. I initially thought `sizeof()` was a macro until I saw that you had said `(ARR)[0]`. As for the `--file` arg being ignored that was intentional, but I do concede that I should have tested for it and then did `printf("file: %s\n", filename)`

Comment: As for the section where you say `Maintaining parallel lists ...` I do agree when it gets to more than 5 args. One solution in the meantime I'd say is to do to somewhat alleviate it is `struct arg{const char* str; unsigned int id;};` and then `struct arg arglist [] = {{"--help", HELP_ARG}, {"-h", HELP_ARG}};` So everything is in one place.

Comment: Yes, or even perhaps `struct arg { const char *option; const char *help; enum ArgType type; void *storage;}`, where `ArgType` determines what gets written to `*storage`.

Comment: Well, that's a little more simple. Where you say *`... void *storage;}`, where `ArgType` determines what gets written to `*storage`* I don't understand; What would storage point to?

Comment: For a boolean flag, the caller would set it to point to a `bool`; for a string argument like `--file`, perhaps to a `const char*` (we can point that at one of the `argv` strings); for an integer argument, it would point to a `int` or `unsigned int` or `long`, etc.  It's something you might want to experiment with - and come here for a review when you have something you're happy with!